# Proof that the angle given by the intersecting line in the square is always 90 degrees

Tags: geometry

Prove that $\angle AHD$ is always $90^\circ$?

$\angle{AHE}$ parallel to $x$-axis

$[BD]$ // $[EF]$

$[AD]$ // $[FG]$

I made a video. I created step by step. [YouTube M372](https://youtu.be/iL9JsZFBjOQ)
[image]

Comment: Hint: In my proof, $\angle ADH \cong \angle GAH$ is a key step near the middle.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You start with a square that's at an angle to the coordinate axes, and you draw a horizontal line at A, and the intersection with BC gives E. Then from E you draw a line parallel to the diagonal BD, and the intersection with CD gives F. Then you draw a line from F parallel to AD, and the intersection with AB gives G. Then you draw DG and the intersection with AE gives H. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Sorry forgot this part, [AD] // [FG]

Comment: i made a video i created step by step. https://youtu.be/iL9JsZFBjOQ

Comment: this proof burn my waffles

Answer (score 4):

One way to get to a proof is to show that $|BE| = |DF| = |AG|$,
using the fact that $\triangle ECF$ is isosceles.

It follows that $\triangle DAG$ is congruent to $\triangle ABE$,
and now you have enough pairs of congruent angles to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that :

1. $\overrightarrow{AB} \perp \overrightarrow{AD}$.
2. $\overrightarrow{BE} \perp \overrightarrow{AG}$.
3. $AG = DF = BE$.

then using the dot product:
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\overrightarrow{AE} \cdot \overrightarrow{DG} & = &  \left(\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BE}\right) \cdot \left(\overrightarrow{DA} + \overrightarrow{AG}\right) \\[2mm]
 & = & \overrightarrow{AB} \cdot \overrightarrow{AG} + \overrightarrow{BE} \cdot \overrightarrow{DA} \\[2mm]
 & = & AB \times AG - BE \times DA \\[2mm]
 & = & AB \times AG - BE \times AB \\[2mm]
 & = & AB \times \left(AG - BE\right) \\[2mm]
 & = & AB \times 0 \\[2mm]
& = & 0
\end{array}$$
We deduce that $(AE) \perp (DG)$ wich means $(AE) \perp (DH)$.